# What is TTGO LoRa?

Tags: lora

I did search for **TTGO** and **LoRA** and found nothing on Google and Bing. I know it is related to Radio frequency but no documentation or website.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoRa

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about acquiring google skills rather than asking an EE question.

Answer (score 2):

*LoRa* is a low power, low bandwidth, long range radio communication technology (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoRa).

*TTGO* is - as far as I understand - a Chinese brand of [LilyGO](http://www.lilygo.cn/) used for microcontroller boards, some including *LoRa* transceivers. Also see their [GitHub page](https://github.com/LilyGO).

It's a mystery why you haven't found anyting because Google returns a ton of hits for *lora ttgo*.

TTGO LoRa boards are readily available on aliexpress.com, banggood.com and ebay.com.